# migration doesn't work in cloned projent in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have cloned the project from Github and tried to run the migration to make the database but it does not work. Why?

I get the following error:

> bash: ./yii: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Path to yii file is incorrect. make sure current directory of command line is set to project root where 'yii' file is stored.

Comment: thanks for your opinion ,i got my problem solved by installing the composer in the cloned project